# Cordova (Ionic2) custom plugin: manage Angular2 new Promise() with cordova.exec() successHandler

Tags: cordova, angular, promise, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I am building a **Cordova plugin** to use with **Ionic2**. I am kind of experienced with Cordova (and custom plugins) but rather new to Ionic2 (and hence also **new at Angular2, TypeScript**).

(What I am asking now, I used to manage it with Jquery Deferred)

In my "app.component.ts" file I have:

```
import...

declare var MyPlugin: any;

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {
  ...
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      MyPlugin.action();
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

I won't detail the "plugin.xml" file for my plugin. This works fine.

The "MyPlugin.js" goes like that:

```
var PLUGIN_NAME = "MyPlugin";

var MyPlugin =function(){};

MyPlugin.action(){
    cordova.exec(
        successResultHandler,
        errorResultHandler,
        PLUGIN_NAME,
        action,
        []
    );
} 
exports.module=MyPlugin;
```

In my Java Class linked to "MyPlugin.js" file I have something like:

```
public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
          //something async
          callbackContext.success()
    }
}
```

When the Java class triggers the `callbackContext.success`, the JS `cordova.exec` will launch the function `successResultHandler`. **I was wondering how to use the Angular2 Promise to catch the async event???**

I started to write some code but it doesn't make sense the order I should use.

I was thinking of doing something like that in "MyPlugin.js":

```
MyPlugin.action(){
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    cordova.exec(
        successResultHandler,
        errorResultHandler,
        PLUGIN_NAME,
        action,
        []
    );
    });
}
```

But of course it doesn't make any sense, how do you catch the result of the function `successResultHandler` in `resolve` that way.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolve and reject parameters that the Promise constructor passes into the callback function are themselves functions, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
MyPlugin.action(){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        cordova.exec(
            resolve,
            reject,
            PLUGIN_NAME,
            action,
            []
        );
    });
};
```

Then invoke it like this:

```
MyPlugin.action().then(() => {
    console.log("Success");
},(err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: I does look like it makes sense. But could not figure out how to make it work as it is written yet. I work around it and let you know.

Comment: This works, mistake was on my side, thanks @DaveAlden for taking my way of thinking out of the box to better understand Angular2 Promise.